# CPTemplate won't load on Carplay

Tags: ios, xcode, carplay

So I followed Apples video on how to make a basic CarPlay app. But I am getting a blank screen instead of a list view.

How can I make a simple list view using the CPTemplate method?

```
import Foundation
import CarPlay

class CarPlaySceneDelegate: UIResponder, CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate {
    var interfactController: CPInterfaceController?
 
  func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene, didConnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
    let item = CPListItem(text: "hello", detailText: "This works")
    let jazz = CPListItem(text: "Jazz", detailText: "How about some smooth jazz.")
  
    let listTemplate = CPListTemplate(title: "TEST", sections: [CPListSection(items:[item,jazz])])
    print("HUGE TEST TO SEE IF THIS IS RUNNING")
    self.interfactController?.setRootTemplate(listTemplate, animated: false)
 
  }
}
```

I know it runs as I get HUGE TEST TO SEE IF THIS IS RUNNING in console log. Just the next line does not run/load.

Comment: Is `interfactController` `nil`?

Comment: I don't know I just get a blank screen. @Paulw11

Comment: What I meant was to check using a print statement or the debugger - is that property `nil`?  I imagine it is. Use the `interfaceController` that was passed to the delegate function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interfaceController is nil. You can initialize it with the interfaceController from the delegate method.

```
func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene, didConnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
self.interfactController = interfaceController
//your code to load template
}
```